# Enable g729 codec for Siphon- iPhone client

Tags: iphone, ios, codec, pjsip

I have a problem of enabling G729 codec. Currently I am using xcode 4.6 to compile Siphon and pjsip 2.1 libraries for making sip calls from iPhone from their official site. I also found source code and can build for both device and simulator from this link.

https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles

I need to work with g729 codec. Can anyone has idea on how do i do that? Kindly share your valuable knowledge on that.

Answer (score 1):

I actually find the [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) source better to pull bits out of.

Basically what you are asking is for the "glue" code between pjsip and the g729 codec.

In csipsimple for g729 it's [here](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple#CSipSimple/jni/g729/pj_sources%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

Then there is just hooking it into the codec framework which is pretty simple, just look how the other codecs are added in already.

You may also like to add it to the pjsip build system to make it easier to build as well, altho that is optional.